# Disabling screen sleep Programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how to prevent the Android Activity from sleep mode programmatically.
Or can we declare something related to this in Android Manifest file.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setKeepScreenOn(true)`

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

You can add this code in your `onCreate()` method of your activity. or you can put it in your xml file

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```