# Persistent app. Device is not going to sleep while my app is running?

Tags: android, sleep

How can I make my device not going to sleep while my application is running, e.g gps is running? I know that might be battery consuming, but for the time being lets get past that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling screen sleep Programatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263868/disabling-screen-sleep-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked before:

[Disabling screen sleep Programatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263868/disabling-screen-sleep-programatically-in-android)

use `setKeepScreenOn(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into a combination of [WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) permission and [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).